# how to use insertion mode in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax in my Asp MVC4 project. My problem is when I try to insert data in my index using Ajax, Only the last data appear, the other data are crushed.how can I use an insertion mode to display all data in my index?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var id = '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_question)'

$.ajax({    
    url: '/Question/ListeOfChoiceSimple/' + id,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_question)").html(result);
       }
});

$.ajax({    
    url: '/Question/ListeOfChoiceDirige/' + id,
    type: 'GET',
    InsertionMode : 'InsertionMode.InsertAfter',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_question)").html(result);
    }
});

</script>
```

Any help please

Comment: Use `append` instead of `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the entire html contents using .html. If you wish to add more markup to the container, consider using the .append instead.

```
$("#@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_question)").append(result);
```